# Which method can be applied to separate ferrofluid liquid from oil?

Tags: materials

I want to know if there is any substance, liquid or any other stuff to separate ferrofluid from oil after mixing them.

Answer (score 2):

Typical ferrofluids are suspension of nano-sized magnetic particles in oil. If you add more of the same oil and mix thoroughly, separation is impossible.

If you add a chemically different oil, you might be able to remove this compound from the mixture again by distillation in vacuum.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to recover the magnetic particles by extraction with a suitable solvent (thinking of petroleum ether or hexanes) in order to get rid of the oil. A frit might come handy.